# How to render a GLUT shape in a internal panel?

Tags: java, swing, glut

I created a simple GUI using swing in Netbeans. The idea is user chooses a shape, enters dimensions, clicks the button to render a GLUT shape in the internal panel (in green) on the GUI. I'm stuck at trying to get the shapes to render on the inner panel.

What is a good method or example to draw or render shapes onto an internal panel or canvas of a GUI?

GUI layout for reference:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ApVE.png]

Update:
Shape Class

```
package swing_tests;
import static com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.Expression.add;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.gl2.GLUT;
/**
 *
 * @author Charlie
 */
public class Shape extends GLJPanel {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    // fields
    int width;
    int height;
    int length;
    String name;

    //Constructor
    public Shape (int w, int h, int l, String n){

        width = w;
        height = h;
        length = l;
        name = n;
    }

    private final GLUT glut = new GLUT();

    // Methods

    public void JOGLShapes() {
        GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(null);
        GLJPanel display = new GLJPanel(caps);
        display.setPreferredSize( new Dimension (50,50));
        display.setVisible(true);
        display.setBackground(Color.red);
        add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

        GL2 gl2 = drawable.getGL().getGL2(); // The object that contains all the OpenGL methods.

        gl2.glClear( GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

        gl2.glLoadIdentity();             // Set up modelview transform.

        glut.glutSolidTeapot(2);

    }

    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        // called when the panel is created
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glClearColor(0.3F, 0.3F, 0.3F, 1.0F);  // TODO: Set background color

        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);  // TODO: Required for 3D drawing, not usually for 2D.
    }

    public void getArea () {
        System.out.println("Area is " + width * height);
    }

    public void getVolume(){
        System.out.println("Volume is "+ width * height * length);
    }


    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    /// Setters
    public void setWidth(int newWidth){
        width = newWidth;
    }
    public void setHeight(int newHeight){
        height = newHeight;
    }
    public void setDepth(int newLength){
        length = newLength;

    }
}
```

Comment: *"GUI layout for reference"* There are times when it's a good idea to post a screenshot of the GUI (e.g. for a layout problem), but this isn't one of them. Post code. Specifically.. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: You're getting closer, but the code you've provided doesn't make much sense. Why are you using the 'solid teapot'? Why do you have "import static com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.Expression.add;"? Again, try to post a compilable example and be clear about what is happening now, and what you want to happen.